# Jw player video analytics

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I am newbie to Jw player.

My requirement is to use Jw player video analytics to my web application.

Now , My videos are in my local system , i do not want to upload it to jw player. So how can i use video analytics plugin?

Comment: I just answered this over at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483065/jw-player-video-analytics-without-uploading-vide>

Comment: I believe you can just upload the URL into JW Player. You don't have to upload the video, just the data.