# Jw player video analytics without uploading vide

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

Is it possible to have video analytics without uploading content to jw player?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on where you want to see your analytics:

- If you want analytics in your **JW Player account dashboard**, you need to either upload the video or add your external content URL. Please see https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2142460-using-jw-player-analytics for more details
- If you want to use **Google Analytics**, add the ga: {} block to your jwplayer().setup() call. You will also need to include the standard GA embed code from Google at the top of your page. Read more about this at https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1417179-integration-with-google-analytics
- If you have **another analytics plugin** on your page, you can use JW Player's Javascript API events to send pings to your analytics:

  jwplayer().on('firstFrame',function(){
    //send a video view event to your analytics engine here
  });

  Read more about this at https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1417188-combining-jw-player-api-events-with-custom-analytics

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actully I do not want my analytics in my JW player account. I want to see this in my local. Is there any way to achieve this? I do not want to upload any video to Jw player as all videos are stored to my local.

Comment: Then you would need to use the third option and send the analytics events back to your local.